# Azure AD - Manage Group & User Assignments

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api, azure-active-directory

*I am an Azure Global Tenant Admin for our [Premium] Azure AD instance. I have a Web App that requires Group/User Assignment to access. We need to know which Groups and Users have been assigned access. The Azure UI does not let you query this information so I am wondering if there is any way to obtain a list of Groups/Users that have been assigned access to a Web App.*

Edit: It looks like the Graph API version 1.5 now supports this. I can download the servicePrincipal ODATA with this URL:

```
GET string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/servicePrincipals?api-version=1.5&$filter=appId+eq+'{1}'",
    tenant, clientId)
```

[According to this MSDN post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/12/12/announcing-the-new-version-of-graph-api-api-version1-5/), I should be able to use a URL format like

```
GET string.Format("https://graph.windows.net/{0}/servicePrincipals/{1}/appRoleAssignedTo?api-version=1.5",
    tenant, clientId)
```

However, I am receiving this error:

> "Resource 'f4126638-cb47-48df-ad9d-57c0684b6575' does not exist or one of its queried reference-property objects are not present."}

Comment: What type of webApp, and what security / identity framework is being used?

Comment: Brendan, the webApp is created in Azure AD as a _Web Application and/or Web API_. The users and groups are sourced from Local Active Directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the second Graph call, I should be using the servicePrincipal's ObjectID returned from the first call instead of the Application's ClientID.